# How to send updated data of an HTML table to another php file?

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I have an html table with two rows, and four columns. First row is not editable, but the cells in the second row are editable. What I need is to find a way to send the updated cell information to another php file. So far I've been using `$_GET['foo'];` and it was working. Until now.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<TR>";
    foreach ($row as $cname => $cvalue) {
        echo "<TD input type=\"text\" name=\"$cname\" contenteditable=\"true\" ALIGN = \"center\"> $cvalue </TD>";
    }
    echo "</TR>";
}
```

In the other php file, I can't seem to get the new data with `$_GET`. Any ideas? I'm going to use the new data to update a row in my database with a MySQL Query.

Here's the whole form.

```
<form action="edit_record_result_final.php" method="get">
<div style="text-align:center">
    <?php
    $typeName = $_GET["typeName"];
    $keyValue = $_GET["keyValue"];
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    if (!mysql_select_db('cmpe')) {
        die('Could not select database: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $sql="SELECT DATA_TYPE
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE table_schema = 'cmpe'
    AND table_name = '$typeName'";
    $sql2="SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE table_schema = 'cmpe'
    AND table_name = '$typeName'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
        $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
        die($message);
    }
    $keyType = mysql_result($result, 0);
    $result = mysql_query($sql2);
    $fieldNum = mysql_result($result, 0);
    $sql="SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'cmpe'
    AND TABLE_NAME ='$typeName'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $header = "";
    echo "<TABLE align=\"center\" BORDER=\"15\" CELLSPACING=\"2\" CELLPADDING=\"4\">";
    echo "<caption> $typeName </caption>";
    echo "<TR>";
    for($i = 0; $i<$fieldNum; $i++){
        $header = mysql_result($result, $i);
        echo "<TD ALIGN = \"center\"><b> $header </b> </TD>";
    }
    echo "</TR>";

    $sql="SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'cmpe'
    AND TABLE_NAME ='$typeName'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
        $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
        die($message);
    }
    $keyName = mysql_result($result, 0);
    if(strcmp($keyType, "varchar")==0) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $typeName
                WHERE $keyName LIKE '$keyValue' ";
    }elseif(strcmp($keyType, "int")==0) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $typeName
                WHERE $keyName = $keyValue";
    }else{
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $typeName
                WHERE $keyName = '$keyValue' ";
    }
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
        die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
    }else{
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<TR>";
            foreach ($row as $cname => $cvalue) {
                echo "<TD input type=\"text\" name=\"$cname\" contenteditable=\"true\" ALIGN = \"center\"> $cvalue </TD>";
            }
            echo "</TR>";
        }
    }

    echo "</TABLE>";

    ?>
    <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's not as hard as you think](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: We would have to see the whole form to see what method you're using to send the information.

Comment: `<TD input type=\"text\"`? why are you combining a `<td>` and `<input>`?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I added the whole form.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @JayBlanchard this is the warning/error: **Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\foo\edit_record_result.php on line 13**

Comment: And I'm getting Undefined Index Error in my edit_record_result_final.php file.

Comment: I didnt think these contenteditable blocks get submitted with the form.  Can you use your network debugging bar in your web browser to make sure that data is actually being sent to the server.

Comment: @KrisZani You might be right. Because I'm able to send data via input text field.

Comment: See my *very first comment*. The `mysql_* functions have been deprecated from your server. You're going to have to change your database API.